# 502 bad gateway Elastic Beanstalk Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a Spring Boot app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I am facing a 502 Bad Gateway error. I cannot find anything useful from the logs

/var/log/nginx/error.log

> 2019/02/10 02:12:54 [error] 3257#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ...., server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "...."

I do not have any html files for front-end. I just want to upload deploy the api to share the documentation from swagger ui.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's because server is listening to 5000, Adding "server.port=5000" to application.properties fixed the issue.

Comment: Mine is simple Java Web app. As per my developer, it's non spring boot app. It's giving the same error as yours. How can it be fixed?

Comment: I added the port config to be 5000 and that did not fix the issue.  it does run just fine on my local machine on port 5000

Comment: maybe they have changed the default port

Answer (score 27):

This happens because the application load balancer by default points to the **Port 80** of the nginx server in EC2 instance. The nginx is configured to forward requests to **Port 5000** by default, whereas out application server runs on **Port 8080**.

**Default Nginx Configuration**

[image: Default Nginx Configuration]

**Expected Nginx Configuration**

[image: Expected Nginx Configuration]

1. This can be fixed using an environment property named `PORT` and pointing it to 8080
   Go to configuration > Environment Properties and add the property
   [image]

Refer AWS Document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html

2. Another option to fix this is to point application load balancer to the application server port(8080) directly instead of the nginx(80.
   You can configure 8080 as the process port.
   [image]
3. Another way to fix this would be to set port to 5000 in the spring boot application by using server.port property.

Comment: In my case "This configuration does not contain a load balancer." so PORT variable in "Environment properties" sorted the problem.

Answer (score 4):

My issue was my `Java` version didn't match the platform I'm running with Elastic Beanstalk, even tho my `server.port` was on `5000`. My Java version was 11, and my platform was only Java 8 for Amazon Linux. So changing it to 8 in my base `pom.xml` fixed it.