# Why is my Elastic Beanstalk environment failing suddenly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have an Elastic Beanstalk project that has been working fine for months. Today, I decide to enable and disable a port listener as seen in the image below:

[image: listeners]

I enabled `port 80` and then the website stopped working. So I was like "oh crap, I will change it back". But guess what? It is still broken. The code has not changed whatsoever, but the application is now broken.

I have restarted the app servers, rebuilt the environment and nothing. I can't even access the environment site by clicking `Go to environment`. I just see a `Bad Gateway` message on screen. The health status of the environment when first deployed is `OK` and then quickly goes to `Severe`.

If my code has not changed, what is happening here? How can I find out what is going on here? All I changed was that port, by enabling and then disabling again.

I have already come across this question: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612962/502-bad-gateway-elastic-beanstalk-spring-boot) and I am already doing this. This environment variable is on my `application.properties` file like this:
`server.port=5000` and it's been like this for months and has already been working. So this can't be the reason that it broke today. I even tried adding it directly to the environment variables in Elastic Beanstalk console and same result, still getting 502 Bad Gateway.

I also have a path for the health-check configured and this has not changed in months.

Here are the last 100 lines from my log file after health status goes to `Severe`:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-engine.log
----------------------------------------
2022/01/27 15:53:53.370165 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker tag af10382f81a4 aws_beanstalk/current-app
2022/01/27 15:53:53.489035 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker rmi aws_beanstalk/staging-app
2022/01/27 15:53:53.568222 [INFO] Untagged: aws_beanstalk/staging-app:latest

2022/01/27 15:53:53.568307 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf eb-docker.service
2022/01/27 15:53:53.576541 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2022/01/27 15:53:53.712836 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2022/01/27 15:53:53.720035 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable eb-docker.service
2022/01/27 15:53:53.866046 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf eb-docker.service
2022/01/27 15:53:53.875112 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active eb-docker.service
2022/01/27 15:53:53.886916 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start eb-docker.service
2022/01/27 15:53:53.991608 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf eb-docker-log.service
2022/01/27 15:53:54.002839 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2022/01/27 15:53:54.092602 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2022/01/27 15:53:54.102854 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable eb-docker-log.service
2022/01/27 15:53:54.226561 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf eb-docker-log.service
2022/01/27 15:53:54.246914 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active eb-docker-log.service
2022/01/27 15:53:54.263293 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start eb-docker-log.service
2022/01/27 15:53:54.433800 [INFO] docker container 3771e61e64ae is running aws_beanstalk/current-app
2022/01/27 15:53:54.433823 [INFO] Executing instruction: Clean up Docker
2022/01/27 15:53:54.433842 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker ps -aq
2022/01/27 15:53:54.638602 [INFO] 3771e61e64ae

2022/01/27 15:53:54.638644 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker images | sed 1d
2022/01/27 15:53:54.810723 [INFO] aws_beanstalk/current-app   latest        af10382f81a4   13 seconds ago   597MB
<none>                      <none>        adafe645300e   24 seconds ago   732MB
openjdk                     8             3bc5f7759e81   30 hours ago     526MB
maven                       3.8.1-jdk-8   498ac51e5e6e   6 months ago     525MB

2022/01/27 15:53:54.810767 [INFO] save docker tag command: docker tag af10382f81a4 aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest
2022/01/27 15:53:54.810772 [INFO] save docker tag command: docker tag adafe645300e <none>:<none>
2022/01/27 15:53:54.810776 [INFO] save docker tag command: docker tag 3bc5f7759e81 openjdk:8
2022/01/27 15:53:54.810781 [INFO] save docker tag command: docker tag 498ac51e5e6e maven:3.8.1-jdk-8
2022/01/27 15:53:54.810793 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker rm `docker ps -aq`
2022/01/27 15:53:54.964217 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker rmi `docker images -aq`
2022/01/27 15:53:56.249352 [INFO] Deleted: sha256:adafe645300e41dd29b04abccf86a562ad5e635bd6afff9343b6a45721fb3a45
Deleted: sha256:b78c0f45b590e7c8c496466450e2fecf2e31044dd53bcf8d9c64a9e7a8c84139
Deleted: sha256:16aedb83589da925c19d2f692234a2a36c017b35846c07fd8ad6817cceda6ae9
Deleted: sha256:a568ba4507a603b7ace044d64726daaf3022c817cc9550779d64dbb95d0e1e5d
Deleted: sha256:fe90a30920d18ecad75ec02e8c04894fbcaadc209529c3e5c14fdaa66d3a7bc9
Deleted: sha256:7c72fe5e2da958b5d44267aa9de538c274e70125c902bc3e663af4c5c87280dc
Untagged: maven:3.8.1-jdk-8
Untagged: maven@sha256:cba6d738a97e81e8845d60ee2662f020385d01d6135a2cf75bc1f5a84980ef88
Deleted: sha256:498ac51e5e6e99ae8646d007ed554587a4ceeab78a664dc7eedde7137c658e9e
Deleted: sha256:de026bec49cbc1fd7bd1bd7aa03d544713985e39bc0a913f4c0a59dbcc556715
Deleted: sha256:f5c45a5e495b035f37dc2e19d8ead0458cf0ad8b83d5573cc9b4016ea54814b6
Deleted: sha256:9f871694bb9a37f62b6baf12760480448d46e008c8c85f06dab5340b16d11a2b
Deleted: sha256:19a57d2c318dfeac5de4cac0a5263af560eff01c620100570c83658e12df0a87
Deleted: sha256:bc20a3f84b95792033865bff3c1cc53b060108ef2018b1913da3c8eddda77b99
Deleted: sha256:f33d6ed931ff64c63168af00c7544d148d01fda66831246572ff2bfcacbcf2d6
Deleted: sha256:017b9704876de2443b332b1dfec580d365184b514eb0af43f1d59637e77af9bb
Deleted: sha256:98fc59c935e697d6375f05f4fa29d0e1ef7e8ece61aed109056926983ada0ef4
Deleted: sha256:c21ff68b02e7caf277f5d356e8b323a95e8d3969dd1ab0d9f60e7c8b4a01c874
Deleted: sha256:afa3e488a0ee76983343f8aa759e4b7b898db65b715eb90abc81c181388374e3

2022/01/27 15:53:56.249384 [INFO] restore docker image name with command: docker tag af10382f81a4 aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest
2022/01/27 15:53:56.249393 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker tag af10382f81a4 aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest
2022/01/27 15:53:56.352957 [INFO] restore docker image name with command: docker tag adafe645300e <none>:<none>
2022/01/27 15:53:56.352988 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker tag adafe645300e <none>:<none>
2022/01/27 15:53:56.360403 [INFO] restore docker image name with command: docker tag 3bc5f7759e81 openjdk:8
2022/01/27 15:53:56.360437 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker tag 3bc5f7759e81 openjdk:8
2022/01/27 15:53:56.461652 [INFO] restore docker image name with command: docker tag 498ac51e5e6e maven:3.8.1-jdk-8
2022/01/27 15:53:56.461677 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker tag 498ac51e5e6e maven:3.8.1-jdk-8
2022/01/27 15:53:56.561836 [INFO] Executing instruction: start X-Ray
2022/01/27 15:53:56.561859 [INFO] X-Ray is not enabled.
2022/01/27 15:53:56.561863 [INFO] Executing instruction: configureSqsd
2022/01/27 15:53:56.561868 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip configure sqsd daemon ...
2022/01/27 15:53:56.561871 [INFO] Executing instruction: startSqsd
2022/01/27 15:53:56.561874 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip start sqsd daemon ...
2022/01/27 15:53:56.561877 [INFO] Executing instruction: Track pids in healthd
2022/01/27 15:53:56.561881 [INFO] This is an enhanced health env...
2022/01/27 15:53:56.561891 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf aws-eb.target | cut -d= -f2
2022/01/27 15:53:56.572170 [INFO] cfn-hup.service docker.service nginx.service healthd.service eb-docker-log.service eb-docker-events.service eb-docker.service

2022/01/27 15:53:56.572206 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf eb-app.target | cut -d= -f2
2022/01/27 15:53:56.583143 [INFO] 

2022/01/27 15:53:56.583747 [INFO] Executing instruction: Configure Docker Container Logging
2022/01/27 15:53:56.587182 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks
2022/01/27 15:53:56.587200 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/postdeploy/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
2022/01/27 15:53:56.587204 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2022/01/27 15:53:56.587325 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"Engine execution has succeeded.","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment completed successfully.","timestamp":1643298836,"severity":"INFO"}]}]}

2022/01/27 15:53:56.587458 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy

2022/01/27 15:56:08.141406 [INFO] Starting...
2022/01/27 15:56:08.141500 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2022/01/27 15:56:08.141523 [INFO] reading event message file
2022/01/27 15:56:08.141619 [INFO] no eb envtier info file found, skip loading env tier info.
2022/01/27 15:56:08.141697 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec

2022/01/27 15:56:08.291283 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:796071762232:stack/awseb-e-zzq77xp3px-stack/a072a330-7f88-11ec-8245-125e3f27604f -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-1
2022/01/27 15:56:08.851246 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:796071762232:stack/awseb-e-zzq77xp3px-stack/a072a330-7f88-11ec-8245-125e3f27604f -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-east-1
2022/01/27 15:56:09.238835 [INFO] checking whether command tail-log is applicable to this instance...
2022/01/27 15:56:09.238847 [INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, thus instance should execute command
2022/01/27 15:56:09.238849 [INFO] Engine command: (tail-log)

2022/01/27 15:56:09.238906 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetTailLogs
2022/01/27 15:56:09.238910 [INFO] Tail Logs...
2022/01/27 15:56:09.239208 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-engine.log


----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/access.log
----------------------------------------
172.31.35.54 - - [27/Jan/2022:15:53:59 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\x82\x02\x92T\xC0\x06O\x7F\xAA\xB5=\xC8\x8Ca\x83v\xFF\xF7\x8E\xF2\xB9\xBDW\x1B\xB9\x9A\x91x\xB0\x81\xBF\xA6\x00\x00&\xC0+\xC0/\xC0#\xC0'\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\xC0,\xC00\xC0$\xC0(\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.31.35.54 - - [27/Jan/2022:15:54:14 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\xBAy5)=k\x1D\x19|\xF6\xBC\xB0B\x10\x0B$\xE8#\x06\x8B\xA1iY\xB4@@+-\x1F\xAC\x92&\x00\x00&\xC0+\xC0/\xC0#\xC0'\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\xC0,\xC00\xC0$\xC0(\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.31.35.54 - - [27/Jan/2022:15:54:29 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\x03\xBC\xF2\x93\x90uW\xC0\xA5f\xFFWz~K_\xF61\xAEsuY\xE2R\xE0\xBC&\xE7\xFB|\xDB\xC2\x00\x00&\xC0+\xC0/\xC0#\xC0'\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\xC0,\xC00\xC0$\xC0(\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.31.35.54 - - [27/Jan/2022:15:54:44 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\x84\xFD\xD5\xA5{\xF7\xDEr\x96\xEB" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.31.35.54 - - [27/Jan/2022:15:54:59 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\xBCU\xC9\x92=\xCBT\xC2\xB8RL\xA3\xF7\xE6\xD4s\xB8!A\xF2\x14\xC3" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.31.85.167 - - [27/Jan/2022:15:55:09 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03f\x1B\xB8\x17\x19k|H\x1DW\xEF&\x83\x03#\xE9GB\xE8f\xB4\xDAGJ]\x8E\x92\xD6\xC8L\xD3%\x00\x00&\xC0+\xC0/\xC0#\xC0'\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\xC0,\xC00\xC0$\xC0(\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.31.35.54 - - [27/Jan/2022:15:55:14 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\xCC\x9D\x1A5&\x99\xB76\x16\xC1\xE2\xB5\xC3:G]\x1A\xA5H\xEE\xF6s\xD0\xF9s\xA3\xBE\xD2\x9Aq\xF0\xC2\x00\x00&\xC0+\xC0/\xC0#\xC0'\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\xC0,\xC00\xC0$\xC0(\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.31.85.167 - - [27/Jan/2022:15:55:24 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03j4x\xF0\x86uwh\x1C\xEEg8\xA9\xA3\x1E(\x18C\x96\xFA\xE8\xA6\x87{\xC3N\xD4\x08\x10\xBA\xAC\x03\x00\x00&\xC0+\xC0/\xC0#\xC0'\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\xC0,\xC00\xC0$\xC0(\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.31.35.54 - - [27/Jan/2022:15:55:29 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\x5C\x8Btq\xBEG\xD2\xF8l\xC8\xBA\x94F\x14\x8F\x1C\xCC\xA1@JSw9\xE4\xCD\xA7\x05\x82\xE4][\xB8\x00\x00&\xC0+\xC0/\xC0#\xC0'\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\xC0,\xC00\xC0$\xC0(\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.31.85.167 - - [27/Jan/2022:15:55:39 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03{\x05\x86\x89\x09.:A\x0C\xCF\x14\xA4=\xDF\xFA\xC6\xD4\xF5+\x9D\xA4\xF8\x93\xE9k\xD5\xD3\xC5\xCA\x9C\xFB\x15\x00\x00&\xC0+\xC0/\xC0#\xC0'\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\xC0,\xC00\xC0$\xC0(\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.31.35.54 - - [27/Jan/2022:15:55:44 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\xBC\xF3\xE3\xDEy\xB3(\xF2\x18\xEB\xC5f\x1F\xA2\xF5\xE6\xF5\x8C\xF6lO\x98D\xFAT\xCB\xB3`\x9C\xC2\xCE.\x00\x00&\xC0+\xC0/\xC0#\xC0'\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\xC0,\xC00\xC0$\xC0(\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.31.85.167 - - [27/Jan/2022:15:55:54 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\x16P\x10\x07}\x90\xBD!\x9E\xA1\xAB\xD9\xDD\x1F\xAA\xBF\x85u\xCF\xE7\xAD\xA9\x93$q\xC4" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.31.35.54 - - [27/Jan/2022:15:55:59 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03x\x94z\x84\x1Buz3\x9A\x8FbX\x07\x13\x00\x8DH\xDFf\x10\xC9\xE7\xDB\xF7\xE7\xBFr\xE8w>\xFC\x9E\x00\x00&\xC0+\xC0/\xC0#\xC0'\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\xC0,\xC00\xC0$\xC0(\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.31.85.167 - - [27/Jan/2022:15:56:09 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\xEF\x1F'\x84@\xF4\xF4\xB6C\xEE\xE4}\xD6E\x94\x05\xA1\x1B*\x1EZ\x94N\xB9K\x96A>\x8A\x8Ep\xBF\x00\x00&\xC0+\xC0/\xC0#\xC0'\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\xC0,\xC00\xC0$\xC0(\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"


----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
----------------------------------------


----------------------------------------
/var/log/docker-events.log
----------------------------------------
2022-01-27T15:52:46.764393026Z image pull maven:3.8.1-jdk-8 (name=maven)
2022-01-27T15:52:47.730944524Z container create b83331900dd580a01b9c5e2744412bd6f6e4465313177fb45a2f288d70765010 (image=sha256:16aedb83589da925c19d2f692234a2a36c017b35846c07fd8ad6817cceda6ae9, name=inspiring_tesla)
2022-01-27T15:52:47.731203832Z container attach b83331900dd580a01b9c5e2744412bd6f6e4465313177fb45a2f288d70765010 (image=sha256:16aedb83589da925c19d2f692234a2a36c017b35846c07fd8ad6817cceda6ae9, name=inspiring_tesla)
2022-01-27T15:52:47.784204703Z network connect 38cc920306e67474a0e4c1558a074911f27746d82bcaf75a013b36aa57d583d3 (container=b83331900dd580a01b9c5e2744412bd6f6e4465313177fb45a2f288d70765010, name=bridge, type=bridge)
2022-01-27T15:52:48.320837501Z container start b83331900dd580a01b9c5e2744412bd6f6e4465313177fb45a2f288d70765010 (image=sha256:16aedb83589da925c19d2f692234a2a36c017b35846c07fd8ad6817cceda6ae9, name=inspiring_tesla)
2022-01-27T15:53:28.504262431Z container die b83331900dd580a01b9c5e2744412bd6f6e4465313177fb45a2f288d70765010 (exitCode=0, image=sha256:16aedb83589da925c19d2f692234a2a36c017b35846c07fd8ad6817cceda6ae9, name=inspiring_tesla)
2022-01-27T15:53:28.615767036Z network disconnect 38cc920306e67474a0e4c1558a074911f27746d82bcaf75a013b36aa57d583d3 (container=b83331900dd580a01b9c5e2744412bd6f6e4465313177fb45a2f288d70765010, name=bridge, type=bridge)
2022-01-27T15:53:30.828196270Z container destroy b83331900dd580a01b9c5e2744412bd6f6e4465313177fb45a2f288d70765010 (image=sha256:16aedb83589da925c19d2f692234a2a36c017b35846c07fd8ad6817cceda6ae9, name=inspiring_tesla)
2022-01-27T15:53:40.412059108Z image pull openjdk:8 (name=openjdk)
2022-01-27T15:53:41.682562011Z container create ebb956fca825c2053c41bce28fb0a802ab2f3ef344bdeb14f821a7577c284138 (image=sha256:2ab20532670b7570e512ec955536dfa5e246c374bdca4f0494df107b88a51c75, name=stoic_fermi)
2022-01-27T15:53:41.807749332Z container destroy ebb956fca825c2053c41bce28fb0a802ab2f3ef344bdeb14f821a7577c284138 (image=sha256:2ab20532670b7570e512ec955536dfa5e246c374bdca4f0494df107b88a51c75, name=stoic_fermi)
2022-01-27T15:53:41.854905318Z container create 28814d73d5d71c7f3cd97d31e3745db7c8d74c7f41a1369d86a6ac94540ff54c (image=sha256:8020ea63973791b37416e569141e448a047578432cc73771afc09069d4a0f99c, name=awesome_ritchie)
2022-01-27T15:53:41.972362390Z container destroy 28814d73d5d71c7f3cd97d31e3745db7c8d74c7f41a1369d86a6ac94540ff54c (image=sha256:8020ea63973791b37416e569141e448a047578432cc73771afc09069d4a0f99c, name=awesome_ritchie)
2022-01-27T15:53:41.978868467Z image tag sha256:af10382f81a47247f3194b007fe0b95c08b2a68c7d9f8f4118741b00121ee217 (name=aws_beanstalk/staging-app:latest)
2022-01-27T15:53:46.962572822Z container create 3771e61e64aec3296f70d863c3deeae6e33d57184feecc1297665eee4630c399 (image=af10382f81a4, name=dreamy_napier)
2022-01-27T15:53:47.000564620Z network connect 38cc920306e67474a0e4c1558a074911f27746d82bcaf75a013b36aa57d583d3 (container=3771e61e64aec3296f70d863c3deeae6e33d57184feecc1297665eee4630c399, name=bridge, type=bridge)
2022-01-27T15:53:47.520980591Z container start 3771e61e64aec3296f70d863c3deeae6e33d57184feecc1297665eee4630c399 (image=af10382f81a4, name=dreamy_napier)
2022-01-27T15:53:53.482805850Z image tag sha256:af10382f81a47247f3194b007fe0b95c08b2a68c7d9f8f4118741b00121ee217 (name=aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest)
2022-01-27T15:53:53.562121224Z image untag sha256:af10382f81a47247f3194b007fe0b95c08b2a68c7d9f8f4118741b00121ee217 (name=sha256:af10382f81a47247f3194b007fe0b95c08b2a68c7d9f8f4118741b00121ee217)
2022-01-27T15:53:55.349273944Z image delete sha256:adafe645300e41dd29b04abccf86a562ad5e635bd6afff9343b6a45721fb3a45 (name=sha256:adafe645300e41dd29b04abccf86a562ad5e635bd6afff9343b6a45721fb3a45)
2022-01-27T15:53:55.351988220Z image delete sha256:16aedb83589da925c19d2f692234a2a36c017b35846c07fd8ad6817cceda6ae9 (name=sha256:16aedb83589da925c19d2f692234a2a36c017b35846c07fd8ad6817cceda6ae9)
2022-01-27T15:53:55.356884258Z image delete sha256:fe90a30920d18ecad75ec02e8c04894fbcaadc209529c3e5c14fdaa66d3a7bc9 (name=sha256:fe90a30920d18ecad75ec02e8c04894fbcaadc209529c3e5c14fdaa66d3a7bc9)
2022-01-27T15:53:55.374500965Z image untag sha256:498ac51e5e6e99ae8646d007ed554587a4ceeab78a664dc7eedde7137c658e9e (name=sha256:498ac51e5e6e99ae8646d007ed554587a4ceeab78a664dc7eedde7137c658e9e)
2022-01-27T15:53:55.376309688Z image untag sha256:498ac51e5e6e99ae8646d007ed554587a4ceeab78a664dc7eedde7137c658e9e (name=sha256:498ac51e5e6e99ae8646d007ed554587a4ceeab78a664dc7eedde7137c658e9e)
2022-01-27T15:53:56.244254893Z image delete sha256:498ac51e5e6e99ae8646d007ed554587a4ceeab78a664dc7eedde7137c658e9e (name=sha256:498ac51e5e6e99ae8646d007ed554587a4ceeab78a664dc7eedde7137c658e9e)
2022-01-27T15:53:56.345382037Z image tag sha256:af10382f81a47247f3194b007fe0b95c08b2a68c7d9f8f4118741b00121ee217 (name=aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest)
2022-01-27T15:53:56.458746013Z image tag sha256:3bc5f7759e81182b118ab4d74087103d3733483ea37080ed5b6581251d326713 (name=openjdk:8)


----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-docker-process.log
----------------------------------------
2022/01/27 15:53:53.917760 [INFO] Loading Manifest...
2022/01/27 15:53:53.917884 [INFO] no eb envtier info file found, skip loading env tier info.
2022/01/27 15:53:53.943756 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:796071762232:stack/awseb-e-zzq77xp3px-stack/a072a330-7f88-11ec-8245-125e3f27604f -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-1
2022/01/27 15:53:57.965132 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:796071762232:stack/awseb-e-zzq77xp3px-stack/a072a330-7f88-11ec-8245-125e3f27604f -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-east-1
2022/01/27 15:53:58.364393 [INFO] Checking if docker is running...
2022/01/27 15:53:58.364409 [INFO] Fetch current app container id...
2022/01/27 15:53:58.364434 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker ps | grep 3771e61e64ae
2022/01/27 15:53:58.402972 [INFO] 3771e61e64ae   af10382f81a4   "java -jar /usr/locaâ€¦"   12 seconds ago   Up 10 seconds   5000/tcp   dreamy_napier

2022/01/27 15:53:58.402996 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker wait  3771e61e64ae


----------------------------------------
/var/log/docker
----------------------------------------
Jan 27 15:50:41 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:50:41.206815429Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
Jan 27 15:50:41 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:50:41.251734173Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Jan 27 15:50:41 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:50:41.251769208Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Jan 27 15:50:41 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:50:41.251794146Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
Jan 27 15:50:41 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:50:41.251813620Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Jan 27 15:50:41 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:50:41.273290447Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Jan 27 15:50:41 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:50:41.273327673Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Jan 27 15:50:41 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:50:41.273364441Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
Jan 27 15:50:41 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:50:41.273386710Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Jan 27 15:50:41 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:50:41.465282859Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Jan 27 15:50:41 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:50:41.956009883Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Jan 27 15:50:42 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:50:42.186887273Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Jan 27 15:50:42 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:50:42.641490298Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=b0f5bc3 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.7
Jan 27 15:50:42 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:50:42.643174227Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Jan 27 15:50:42 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:50:42.702629222Z" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Jan 27 15:53:28 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:53:28.503145956Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=b83331900dd580a01b9c5e2744412bd6f6e4465313177fb45a2f288d70765010 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jan 27 15:53:41 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:53:41.783532791Z" level=info msg="Layer sha256:e963a094d3f25a21ce0bfcae0216d04385c4c06ad580c73675a7992627c28416 cleaned up"
Jan 27 15:53:41 ip-172-31-85-60 docker: time="2022-01-27T15:53:41.948756315Z" level=info msg="Layer sha256:e963a094d3f25a21ce0bfcae0216d04385c4c06ad580c73675a7992627c28416 cleaned up"


----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/eb-3771e61e64ae-stdouterr.log
----------------------------------------

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.6)


2022-01-27 15:53:57.807  INFO 3771e61e64ae --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.w.EndpointLinksResolver        : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2022-01-27 15:53:57.853  INFO 3771e61e64ae --- [           main] o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol                : Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-5000"]
2022-01-27 15:53:57.875  INFO 3771e61e64ae --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer              : Tomcat started on port(s): 5000 (http) with context path ''
2022-01-27 15:53:57.903  INFO 3771e61e64ae --- [           main] c.n.p.ParalleniumHostApplication         : Started ParalleniumHostApplication in 8.805 seconds (JVM running for 10.386)
2022-01-27 15:53:57.939  INFO 3771e61e64ae --- [           main] c.n.p.ParalleniumHostApplication         : **The server is hosted at: 127.0.0.1:5000 with a PUBLIC ip of 34.226.166.24
2022-01-27 15:53:57.941  INFO 3771e61e64ae --- [           main] c.n.p.ParalleniumHostApplication         : Spring version is 5.3.12
2022-01-27 15:53:57.946  INFO 3771e61e64ae --- [           main] c.n.p.ParalleniumHostApplication         : Socket Server is listening on port 6868...
```

Comment: NGINX logs look like you are trying to make a TLS connection to port 80 (the non-TLS port)

Comment: I actually was trying to do that at one point (not realized that was incorrect at the time). Would that cause the entire app to fail like this though?

Comment: And where are you seeing that in my logs?

Comment: `/var/log/nginx/access.log`

Comment: What does that section even mean? It doesn't look readable. What do you recommend I do?

Comment: It just looks like a TLS request being sent through a non TLS port. I recognize that from prior experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I decided to just launch a new environment using the same exact configuration and code and it worked. Looks like Elastic Beanstalk environments can break and once that happens, there is no fixing it apparently.