# Configuring server and port for Tomcat Spring Boot application

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, port

I am deploying my Spring Boot application via uploading a JAR to Elastic Beanstalk.

[image]

I am getting the following error:

`*1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.43.15, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "172.31.42.2"`

and
[image]

I do not understand which configurations are missing. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-proxy.html) it says:

> The Tomcat platform uses nginx (the default) or Apache HTTP Server as the reverse proxy to relay requests from port 80 on the instance to your Tomcat web container listening on port 8080. Elastic Beanstalk provides a default proxy configuration that you can extend or override completely with your own configuration.

I feel like this should give me some hint, but I still don't get what exactly I need to change.

Similar issue: [502 bad gateway Elastic Beanstalk Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612962/502-bad-gateway-elastic-beanstalk-spring-boot)
From the suggestions there I tried:

- defining `server.port=8080` in my `application.properties`
- adding PORT or SERVER_PORT environment properties directly in EB
- changing Java to version 8 in `pom.xml`
- changing load balancers ports here in EB to 8080:
  [image]

I might be changing things to a wrong port, or maybe in an unfortunate combination - but nothing seems to work for me.

I never had to do such things, so for me it's all super unclear and I would be thankful for all kinds of help.

Comment: change your spring boot application port to 5000. Everything will work fine. Nginx maps the port 5000 to port 80 by default without configuration.

Comment: that's tomcat which give you the 404 so it's not port issue.