# Why am I getting a 502 error on my Spring Boot app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have recently deployed my Spring Boot app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The environment is ok, and I am running an EC2 instance on it. However, when I actually go to the domain, I get a 502 Bad Getaway error. I even receive this error in spite of AWS saying that the environment is ok.

Here is the code for my applications.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:letscook
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
server.error.include-messages=always

spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
```

Comment: [502](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502) suggests something is configured incorrectly. Do you have [Cloudwatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/)? Otherwise can you shell into the EC2 instance and check for logs there? Is spring running?

Comment: @rkochar Do not have cloudwatch and Spring is not running in Eclipse

Comment: what error do you get when you start spring? Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612962/502-bad-gateway-elastic-beanstalk-spring-boot?rq=2).

Comment: @rkochar No errors in spring

Comment: @rkochar Do you need an RDS in order for the web app to work?

Comment: your spring config has Postgre in it. It would seem logical that you need a RDS. Does this [tutorial](https://jstw.github.io/deploy-spring-rest-api-with-rds-db-on-elb/) help?